# Publish Windows service in Microsoft store with NodeJS or Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, windows-services, windows-store-apps, electron-builder

I'm looking for a the golden advice.

I've created an app that listens to websockets over a certain port and then sends commands to a native module (wrapped by NodeJS). now all this is done in NodeJS app. and packed in exe file (with two extra files for the native module ".dll and .napi")

now I want two things:

1. Run this app as a windows service in the background.
2. Package it in an installer that should stop the service (if exists), install the new update, then re-run the service. this app will be published in Microsoft store as appx.

I'm new to all of this so I feel lost while trying to know which is the best approach with my little knowledge.

I'm a bit confused between NodeJS and ElectronJS, some people say electron is not the best choice for services, but electron-builder is a great tool for packaging.

Conclusion: I want to publish my app to Microsoft store (already bought a developer account), and to run it as a service (no GUI). and the code is written in JS (node or electron)

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, did you manage since then ?

Comment: @Adnane.T I used electronjs with electron-builder. you can set the app to start minimized with minimal UI (a good looking logo wont harm).

Comment: Sounds good, still not a windows service though right?

Comment: Yes, not a real windows service. if you want to go that way, you need to handle auto updates manually. fortunately, electron-builder do all the magic.